# React ESLint error at line that doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using nextjs and when i run `next build` it fails and gives the error below. The error points me to line 19 (which is an empty line) and line 33 (which doesn't even exist?).

For the error message itself, I saw an issue with `eslint-plugin-react` which has supposedly been fixed recently, but I'm still getting the error with the newest updated version in `package-lock.json`:

```json
"eslint-plugin-react": ">=7.29.4",
```

I have also tried deleting the `.next` folder and doing `next build` again, and deleting `node-modules` and doing `npm install`, the error still happens.

File with the error:

```js
import Subtitle1 from './subtitle-1'
import Subtitle2 from './subtitle-2'

class SwitchSubtitle extends Component {
    constructor(...args) {
      super(...args);
      this.state = {
        stitles: [<Subtitle1/>, <Subtitle2/>],
        index: 0
      };
    }
  
    componentDidMount() {
      this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({index: this.state.index + 1})
      }, 3500)
    }
  
    render() {
      const { index, stitles } = this.state;
      return(
          <p>{stitles[index % 2]}</p>
      );
    }
}

export default SwitchSubtitle
```

Error given from `next build`:

```
info  - Checking validity of types

Failed to compile.

./components/landing/switchSubtitle.js
9:19  Error: Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
9:33  Error: Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
```

Comment: As far as i can see the only array containing components is `stitles: [<Subtitle1/>, <Subtitle2/>]`. Try to add keys there. `stitles: [<Subtitle1 key="0"/>, <Subtitle2 key="1"/>],`

Comment: Adding that fixed the original error, but now I'm getting this:

`Failed to compile.`

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './C:/Users/Ishaan/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/next/dist/client/next.js' in 'E:\Programming\testsite'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you render an array of components each element needs a `key` that’s unique within the array.

You’re effectively rendering such an array here:

```
stitles: [<Subtitle1/>, <Subtitle2/>]
```

You could add keys, like this:

```
stitles: [<Subtitle1 key=“1”/>, <Subtitle2 key=“2”/>]
```

But I think a better approach would be to put the components themselves in the array and defer rendering until it’s needed. This way you’re only rendering the component that’s actually being displayed:

```
stitles: [Subtitle1, Subtitle2]

// …

const Cmp = stitles[index % 2];

return (
   …
   <Cmp />
   …
)
```

Comment: I still get the missing "key" error when I do the second recommended option you mentioned

Comment: Did you remove the `<>` from the array elements?

Comment: Ok that fixed it, but now I'm getting this: 

`Failed to compile. Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './C:/Users/Ishaan/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/next/dist/client/next.js' in 'E:\Programming\testsite'`

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this case the error is a little missleading, what it propably means is that you just simple need to pass a key to this component(assuming your mapping it)

Try adding key to p element

```
  return(
      <p key={index}>{stitles[index % 2]}</p>
  );
```

Comment: Tried this, deleted .next folder and did next build. Same error at the same lines. Could it be somehow interpreting an older version of the code in cache somehow? I also mentioned that this was a known issue about a month ago but is supposed to be fixed now so I'm not sure about that either

Comment: @Ishaan Definitely no cache, can you add to your question components where you use SwitchSubtitle component?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you nead the array stitles as state, the fact that the index is being incremented and the state being changed and the render function being trigged is enough, why don't you try this :

```
return(
   {index%2 == 0 ? (
     ....
     <Subtitle1/>
     ...
   ) : (
     ...
     <Subtitle2/>
     ...
   )}
);
```

Comment: Adding that fixed the original error, but now I'm getting this: 

`Failed to compile. Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './C:/Users/Ishaan/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/next/dist/client/next.js' in 'E:\Programming\testsite'`

Comment: Now, I thinks it's a new problem related to the use of nextJs, try for example to delete npm modules and delete the cach and re-install averything ? 
If the code did solve the problem, please don't forget to vote up !